# GetPropertyInfo fails for some properties

Tags: c#

I´ve been searching and trying for some hours now but it doesn´t make sense to me right now.
Basically I have two class libraries in a .net 4.5 project.

On using reflection I´m able to access some properties but not all and I d not see my fault.

Library A defines the datastructure:

```
   public class HeaderRow
    {
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public Int32 Version { get; set; } = 0;
        public CustomEnum Datacategory { get; set; }
        public Custom2Enum FormatnameEnum { get; set; }
        public  int Formatversion { get; set; }
        public UInt64 CreatedAt { get; set; } 
        public string Origin {get; set;}
    }
```

which I´d like to fill in library 2 with this code:

```
 protected PropertyInfo FindPropertyInfo(object o, string propertyName)
        {
            Type objektTyp = o.GetType();

        PropertyInfo info = objektTyp.GetProperty(propertyName,BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic);
return info;
}

        public override void FillValueToColumns(object o, string property, string value)
        {
            FindPropertyInfo(o,property).SetValue(o,value);
        }
```

I have access to:
Format but not Origin
CreatedAt but not Formatversion
and I do not see my custom Enums.

For all those I do not see "info" is null.
Any help is apreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are passing in the correct property name string? Are you sure library 2 is referencing the up-to-date version of library A?

Comment: Could be a casing issue `BindingFlags.IgnoreCase`

Comment: You are also trying to set a string value on non-string properties.

Comment: @Crowcoder, yes, I´m quite sure. Both libraries are in one solution. I basically copied and pasted all properties at once (as they are from an interface description I have to implement) and finally I created a test-Property which shows up if I expand "objektTyp" in Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use SetValue to assign a string to, for example, an int. To do that you will either need overloads of FillValueToColumns that take the int (for example) as the last parameter, or else you need to get a type converter, like this:

```cs
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = FindPropertyInfo( o, propertyName);
TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( propertyInfo.PropertyType);
object v = typeConverter.ConvertFrom( null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, value ?? "");
if (v == null && propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) == null) {
    throw new InvalidCastException("Assignment of null to a non-nullable value type!");
}
propertyInfo.SetValue( object, v);
```

sjb

Comment: Sorry, don't know why the formatting didn't work. Cut and paste to VS to read it, I guess.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have a setting issue. As the "getPropertyInfo" is part of a baseClass I use. The base class just has to find the Property. I use a set of formatter classes to determine the right type an a chain of resposibility to set the valued. Basically I tried to adapt the (SuperCSV Idea: https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to you. My bad. Sorry.
Indeed a naming issue.

By copy & paste I created blanks in my string properties. So I was searching for

> "Origin "

and not

> "Origin"

-> Deleting surplus blanks solved the issue.

Comment: Would recommend using "nameof" to avoid this kind of problem.